# Can I use specific version of VUEJS in Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am new to the VUEJS and learning it by torrent.
The author use docs from old version https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

for example .sync was added only in 2.3.0 version

```
<text-document v-bind:title.sync="doc.title"></text-document>
```

Can I use specific version(like 2.2) of VUEJS with laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses `NPM` (node package manager), and any module gets into `node_modules` directory.

- Install `Node.js`.
- Open terminal and `cd` into your project root.
- Then just run:

```
npm install --save vue v2.3
```

> **Note** that above may fail if there is a dependency conflict (and fixing that is out of the OP's scope).

So, it doesn't matter that you are new to `Vue` as long as you know enough to prepare Laravel (and can ensure it's `package.json` does not conflict).